# Should one transcribe granular 16th information in sung melodies?

Tags: voice, rhythm, transcription

I'm noticing a lot of the sung melodies to my favorite songs have weird looking 16th note offsets like melodies landing on "e" and "a" in 1e&a. This turns an easy to read phrase with straight eighth notes and quarters into something I struggle to read, but I don't have much experience reading music. On one hand it's good for me to train my sense of rhythm in the 16ths but on the other hand I worry if I'm making it hard for everyone notating it all out

Comment: Is the piece swung?

Answer (score 15):

Whether you transcribe literally or not depends on your purpose. If you want to communicate as precisely as possible how the melody is sung, then use the greatest granularity manageable. However, if your goal is just to communicate the pitches, lyrics, and the general feel of the song — but rely on listening to a recording for the actual learning — then an approximation is fine.

In popular music and jazz, singers rarely sing what is literally written. That's the reason that transcriptions wind up with so many rhythmic complexities. If the song was ever written out to begin with, it was likely written using very simple rhythms, thereafter relying on the singer's own sense of musicality to determine the precise timing. In that sense, simplifying the rhythms would be more accurate — meaning, it's probably closer to the actual source material. Again, though, if the goal is to accurately imitate a specific performance, then granular rhythmic notation is the way to communicate the literal performance, and doesn't rely on learning by listening.

Comment: This video by Adam Neely makes a similar point about the purpose of notation being (broadly) to communicate the music rather than to attempt to be a transcription of exactly the sounds made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUHEPmg0sPo

Comment: "whether you transcribe literally or not" Or to be more precise, *how* literal you decide to be with your transcription. More of a spectrum than a dichotomy. +1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should transcribe melodies as accurately as possible, melody notes starting on unaccented 16th notes such as the "a" in "1e&a" and all.

You will eventually run into melodies that use dotted 8th-16th note rhythms as well as melodies that have note starts on Beat X.75 (the "a" in "1e&a") and place ties on those notes so they are held over into adjacent beats.

Nastily, the famed *Super Mario Bros.* overworld theme not only has notes that start on Beat X.75 and significant amounts of syncopation, it also even has 8th-note triplets! Today's music does not go easy on you rhythm-wise.

In some circles, you can get away with doubling the tempo and notating what would be 16th notes as 8th notes instead, but the syncopation problem remains, and readers will still need to deal with notes on the "&" of "4&".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should notate these 16th note rhythms as originally performed.

16th note rhythms are not too granular to notate exactly.  It makes sense to simplify very minor rhythmic details, such as slightly late downbeats, for example.  These details could be left to "interpretation" or "feel".  But 16th notes are still in the realm of "coarse" rhythm, not "fine" rhythm, so to speak.

Also, good notation matters.  Follow the basic rules about beaming, so your rhythms are not unnecessarily difficult to read.  There's only a few combinations of sixteenth notes that can fit in a beat, so they end up forming visual "words" that an experienced reader will recognize quickly.  If you use an unusual "spelling" for these "words" (iow, mathematically equivalent, but less common, notation), it will trip up the reader.